# Automatically attach a header from frontend app to external http request?

Tags: angular, reactjs, vue.js, axios, frontend

let's say I have some request logics in my frontend app. Some of them are for api.foo.com, while others, api.bar.com.

I want to set a header HELLO="WORLD"(the value can be constant or dynamic(provided by js)) on every request to api.foo.com, but not api.bar.com.

As manually specifying the same header to many requests is cumbersome and error-prone, I want it to be automatic.
Currently, I think this can be done by customizing http client. For example, I can wrap axios and inject some header logic in it, and use the object instead of plain axios.

However, I wonder if there's more elegant or recommended ways(Or please just share any possible solutions).

Currently, I'm using Vue, but share other framework-specific solutions as well, because I believe other people might find yours helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Axios interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors). Write something like this:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
  if (request.url.includes('api.foo.com')) request.headers['HELLO'] = 'WORLD';
  return request;
});
```

Live [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Shapell/pen/jOPLvZL?editors=1010).

If you need to send some data to the interceptor, see [here](https://dev.to/teroauralinna/global-http-request-and-response-handling-with-the-axios-interceptor-30ae) how to do this.

Comment: Thanks! That would be one of possible solutions!
But there is no similar concept of intercepter in plain browsers' js API?